# What does C.M. mean above a measure?

Tags: notation

I'm playing Linus and Lucy and when it changes after the intro and the repeated chords to a different feel and rhythm, there is a C.M. above that measure where it changes.  What does this mean?

Comment: Hi Jodie, would it be possible for you to upload an image of this notation? Also, what instrument are you playing this piece on?

Comment: You must mean the "swing feel" section... probably a cup mute indication on a trumpet chart.

Comment: "cup mute" looks good. could it ev. be:  consider (take acount) measure?

Comment: Possibly a poorly - printed "Cm" for C-minor ?

Answer (score 3):

It means [Common Meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_metre). It's an old american marking that is quite unusual these days.

Comment: Common Meter would have no useful meaning in this context.  Let's see a scan.

Answer (score 1):

You sure it's not "N.C." ?  I see that in several online sheet music versions of this song.  [Dolmetsch Online](https://www.dolmetsch.com/defsn.htm) says that means

> chord symbols, there may be a bar (or several of them) that has no
>   chord symbol. In this case, the performer continues playing the same
>   chord as indicated in the previous bar (or measure). N.C., meaning 'no
>   chord', is used where no specific chord is to be used at that point in
>   the music, although when the melodic material has a strong harmonic
>   element the marking N.C. is probably inappropriate [entry prompted by
>   Tammy Ford]

Comment: Hmm... That does occur in that section, but I think that N.C. would rarely be misidentified as C.M. +1 for the idea, though!